# Reuse a route path for a custom page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url, routes, custom-routes

I have a controller named "materiels"
I wanted a custom url for all content from this controller, so I have write this in routes. rb

```
resources :materiels, path: 'materiel-de-mangaka'
```

Until now, all is fine. I create content and all the content have this custom url
Now I want to create a custom page papier.html.erb and reuse the url in order to like /materiel-de-mangaka/papier

So I add this line in routes.rb

```
get '/materiel-de-mangaka/papier' => 'materiels#papier'
```

So it doesn't working...
How I can route papier.html.erb page by reusing the same url path to become materiel-de-mangaka/papier without create a new content ?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If it is under a controller: "/controller name/action name"

`resources :materiels do
       member do
          get 'papier' 
       end
    end`

If it is only "/action name"

```
get "papier"  => "materiels#papier"
```

Comment: Thank you. No, I want to use the "materiel-de-mangaka" for the "materiels" resources, but I want use this url to, for "materiel-de-mangaka/papier" html.erb page.